# code for selecting a radio button when i will select a hyper link provided in the same row

Tags: javascript

i want a code for selecting a radio button when i will select a hyper link provided in the same row

like

radio1     groupcode1    mappedusers    mappeddomains   mappedroles
radio2     groupcode2    mappedusers    mappeddomains   mappedroles
radio3     groupcode3    mappedusers    mappeddomains   mappedroles

here mappedusers mappesdomains and mappedroles are hyperlinks provided for the groupcode.
If i will select any link, radio button in the same row should select.

Comment: can you provide the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure without seeing some code, but with jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("a.MappedRoles").click(function (e)
    {
        $(this).siblings("input.Select").attr("checked", "checked");
    });
});
```

This will attach to the `click` event of your "Mapped Roles" links (assuming you've given them the class "MappedRoles"). When a link is clicked, a sibling is located which is an `input` with the class "Select" - it is then checked by adding the "checked" attribute.

Post your code and I can make this work for your situation if you can't quite get it.

Answer (score 0):

And in plain js, you can add a listener on the table that looks to see where a click comes from. :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// A helper functions

// Return ancestor of el with tagname or
// undefined if no such parent
function upTo(el, tag) {
  tag = tag.toLowerCase();
  do {
    el = el.parentNode;
  } while (el && el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() != tag)

  return el.tagName? el : null; 
}


// Check first radio button in row of clicked link
function doRadioThing(el, evt) {

  // Helper function, specific to this fn so
  // keep local
  function getFirstRadio(el) {
    var inputs = el.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++){
      if (inputs[i].type == 'radio') return inputs[i];
    }
  }

  // Get ref to element clicked on
  var src  = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

  // Only proceed if it was an A element:
  if (src && src.tagName && src.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a') return;

  // Get parent TD
  var cell = src  && upTo(src, 'td');

  // Get parent TR
  var row  = cell && cell.parentNode;

  // Get first radio button in row
  var inp  = row  && getFirstRadio(row);

  // Uncheck first radio button in each row if there is one 
  // so only the one in the row that was clicked on is checked
  // May not be a requirement
  var rows = el.rows;
  for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var radio = getFirstRadio(rows[i]);
    radio && (radio.checked = false);
  }

  // Check input in row of clicked link if there is one
  inp && (inp.checked = true);
}

</script>



<table  onclick="doRadioThing(this, event);">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" id="r0">
    <td><a href="#">mappedusers</a>
    <td><a href="#">mappesdomains</a>
    <td><a href="#">and mappedroles</a>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" id="r1">
    <td><a href="#">mappedusers</a>
    <td><a href="#">mappesdomains</a>
    <td><a href="#">and mappedroles</a>
</table>
```